# Convert seconds into T1H15M5S (ISO_8601)

Tags: java, time, converters, duration

I would like to convert a number of seconds into ISO_8601/Duration in Java.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Are there any existing methods to do it that are already built in?

Comment: research mainly, Google, Stackoverflow why?

Comment: because it seems to me like a simple formating on tostring method. i don't know which params do you need, but it seems simple enough

Comment: with the mod function i guess and doing the other math by myself. But the question is to know if there is something existing. I am probably no the first one trying to do this (i hope).

Comment: can you tell me how the format's going to be, like HH:MM:SS:mm?

Comment: T1H15M5S - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Comment: Since ISO8601 allows for certain variations, do you really need the duration formatted as in your example, or do you just need any valid ISO8601 compliant format?

Comment: I am doing this based on this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2413309?hl=en&ref_topic=1088474 so i guess any valid with the ISO8601 should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ISO 8601 allows for the individual fields in a duration string to overflow, you could just prepend "PT" to the number of seconds and append "S":

```
int secs = 4711;
String iso8601format = "PT" + secs + "S";
```

This will output "PT4711S", which is equivalent to "PT1H18M31S".

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the Period object from the [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library.  Then you could write a method like so:

```
public static String secondsAsFormattedString(long seconds) {
     Period period = new Period(1000 * seconds);
     return "PT" + period.getHours() + "H" + period.getMinutes() + "M" + period.getSeconds() + "S";
 }
```

Comment: @jarnbjo I tested it and it does.  `secondsAsFormattedString(60*60*24*2 + 62)` => `PT48H1M2S`.  
What is your output?

Comment: You are right, I didn't actually try it. As often is the case with the Joda API documentation, the documentation for the Period class is inconsistent and the constructor Period(long) does not populate the "standard set of fields" as stated, assuming that with the "standard set of fields" the "standard period type" is ment, "which supports years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds and millis".

Answer (score 1):

### [`Duration#ofSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofSeconds-long-)

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Duration.ofSeconds(4711));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT1H18M31S
```

Answer (score 0):

I second the recommendation of the JodaTime library; but I suggest toString() or Joda's ISOPeriodFormat class since small periods (like 300 seconds) will show as "PT0H5M0S" which although correct, may fail things like (poorly written) ISO certification tests expecting "PT5M".

```
Period period = new Period(1000 * seconds);

String duration1 = period.toString();
String duration2 = ISOPeriodFormat.standard().print(period);
```

Although I've never seen period.toString() give an incorrect result, I use ISOPeriodFormat for clarity.